# Flutter: Send data one by one after successful API response to an API from a for loop

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I have a for loop which returns data from a list .

```
for (ClientModel data in clientData) {
```

and if the data has a key it has to go to a API (POST request) request as the body.
So I check for a key for that that

```
                if (clientData.contains(data.key)) {
```

and then send to a function inside a provider class like this

```
await Provider.of<ClientProvider>(context, listen: false)
                  .sendClients(context, client);
```

My problem is that in this code all the API requests are calling at one time(by the time for loop runs which is a very small time) .

I want to adjust this code to wait for the first API request to complete and then only run the next in line API request.

How can I achieve that?

Edit:

```
    sendClientData(context, ClientNewModel data) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final authToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
  int id;
  String editUrl = "";
  if (data.id != null) {
    // print(data.id);

    id = data.id;
    editUrl = "/$id/edit";
  }

  try {
    print("Time stamp ${DateTime.now()}");
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.https(BASE_URL, GET_CLIENTS + editUrl, {'q': '{http}'}),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader:"application/json",
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "$authToken"
      },
      body: json.encode(data.toJson()),
    );

    print(response.body);
    debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
    log(json.encode(data.toJson()));
    if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else if (response.statusCode == 403 ||
        response.statusCode == 404 ||
        response.statusCode == 401 || response.statusCode == 402 || response.statusCode == 422) {
      Toast.show("Sync failed \n ${response.body}", context,backgroundColor: Colors.red, textColor: Colors.white,duration: 3);
    } else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
      Toast.show("Server error", context,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red, textColor: Colors.white);
    } else {
      logLongString(data.toJson().toString());

      Toast.show("Server error", context,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red, textColor: Colors.white);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    Toast.show("Server error", context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red, textColor: Colors.white);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regular (for in) will not wait for the request to finish so instead you can

```
await Future.forEach(clientData, (ClientModel data) async {
  await Provider.of<ClientProvider>(context, listen: false).sendClients(context, client);
});
```

you can try this first

```
for (var o in objects) {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
   print("data");
});
}
```

if work fine then the problem might be from your `sendClients` method

Comment: This method did not work . I printed time stamps for API requests and all went at the same time                          I/flutter ( 4692): Time stamp 2021-04-27 16:56:55.460877
I/flutter ( 4692): Time stamp 2021-04-27 16:56:55.489973
I/flutter ( 4692): Time stamp 2021-04-27 16:56:55.491662
I/flutter ( 4692): Time stamp 2021-04-27 16:56:55.492934

Comment: for your last solution all the API call run after 500ms delay. Did not solve the issue.

Comment: it is not solution .. it is  test since asynchronous call like  Future.delayed is working fine .. 
the problem might be in `sendClients` . have you tried it alone and worked fine  ?

Comment: I have added the sendClients function to the original post. Please check

Comment: is calling `sendClientData` gives you a response or exit directly ?